# Activity Recognition updates does not start unless I restart phone

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I am using Activity Recognition service in my application. Sometimes, the service stops suddenly and it works only if I restart the phone.

In Nexus 5, it is not starting even after restart

I have latest google play services version 4.3.23

Thanks in advance

Comment: The service stops while running the app or if the device goes to sleep?

Comment: If I disconnect and connect back. It does not start

Comment: I'm having the same issue. You can re-register the intents for updates but it only works if you restart the device.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue  ?I am also stuck on the same thing

Comment: Still have the issue in 2022